# How can I make my bot read custom status?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hey I was just wondering if its possible to make my bot read users custom status so if it matches it gives the a role, By this I mean If they have my discord server invite link they recieve the supporter role is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Check the [User#Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=presence) part.

Then you can get their status and even their activity message.

To add a role to a member, make sure to check [GuildMemberRoleManager#add](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.

It's included in the activities:

```
message.member.guild.presences.cache
```

This will return all the activities from all members in a guild.

Discord.js: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities

Comment: And how can I do this like:

`if (message.member.guild.presences.cache === 'DISCORDINVITE') {

}` 

?

Comment: I suggest looping through all of them, and if it hae the desired presence, do something with it. Also, the presences include: WATCHING - LISTENING - STREAMING and PLAYING, if I'm correct.